# Partition type FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF, drive unmountable How do I fix this?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, startup, guid

I started having this issue when I tried to swap  my sshd for an ssd. My caddy was broken so I tired booting into bootcamp to run disk cloning software.

(Seagate backup time machine disk failed on me. I should have bought a new one on during the sales)

Windows 8 ran the disk startup utility which allowed me to boot. However, once I restarted I could no longer boot into osx and I got the dreaded all f partition type.

I followed a few posts on here and was able to get my partitions visible. Bootcamp is visible with no issues but my osx partition is still unmountable.

Have reinstalled OSX on the new ssd and have mounted the old drive in a drive caddy.

[image: disk util info disk1s2]

I'd really appreciate some support on this.

Thanks
Iridium

Comment: Do you know if you were using Mac OS Extended (Journaled), Core Storage or APFS?

Comment: Thanks for the question David. Turns out I had APFS but had added the partition using the cold storage ID. Thanks to your question and a bunch of posts by Klanomath I was able to recover the drive and boot. I’ll post exactly what I did when I get back from work.